# Remove All Instances of String in Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, text

Let's say I have an array with the following contents: `"@@@Some Text###","@@@More Text###","@@@Even more Text###","@@@Even Even More Text###"`

And I wanted to remove all instances of `@@@` and `###`. I tried to do this with the following function, but the returned array is exactly the same, as seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Wulff/u5ms64jp/):

```
function removeText(start, end, array) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var text = array[i];
        text.split(start).join("");
        text.split(end).join("");
        newArray.push(text);
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

I assume that there is some very simple reason that I can't get this to work, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should be better using Replace instead of Split in this case, see the implementation at here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I assume you debugged this. Walk through your code line by line. For instance, after stepping over the line `test.split(start).join("");`, examine the variable `test` and see what its value is.

Comment: Your question says "remove all instances". Yet your variable naming uses `start` and `end`. Do you want to remove them only at the start and end, or everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split method doesn't modify the original string, instead it returns a new value, so make sure that you reassign it to text so that you are actually modifying the `array[i]` instance:

```
text = text.split(start).join("");
text = text.split(end).join("");
```

And here's your [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/u5ms64jp/1/).

Comment: Great, that's the one. Thanks! (I'll accept it as soon as I can)

Answer (score 0):

How about given:

```
var myArray = [
      "@@@Some Text###",
      "@@@More Text###",
      "@@@Even more Text###",
      "@@@Even Even More Text###"];
```

Then you might

```
myArray = myArray.map(function(item){
    return item.replace("@@@", "").replace("###", "");
});
```

Comment: That will replace `@@@ and `###` anywhere in the string. Perhaps you would be better off with `replace(/^@@@|###$/, '')`.

Comment: Good point, though the OP stated: "I wanted to remove all instances of @@@ and ###"  but I agree, your regex is probably what they wanted

Answer (score 0):

In modern JS:

```
function removeText(start, end, array) {
  let regexp = new Regexp(`^${start}|${end}$`, 'g');
  return array.map(elt => elt.replace(regexp, '');
}
```

In the real world you would want to escape `start` and `end` to deal with the case where they contain magic regexp characters.